# Handle incoming call from twilio in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: twilio

I have an existing WebApi that i want to handle incoming twilio calls.

I used this tutorial(https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls-csharp) and created a sample controller that I've attached to my existing project.

Controller:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;
using Twilio.TwiML;

namespace SS.RestServer.Controllers
{
    public class VoiceController : TwilioController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public TwiMLResult Index(Twilio.AspNet.Common.VoiceRequest request)
        {
            var response = new MessagingResponse();
            response.Message("Hello World");
            return TwiML(response);
        }
    }
}
```

but when i call it like this:
http://localhost:XXXXX/Voice

I get 404

Is there a way to return TwiML MessagingResponse without inheriting from TwillioController? this way i dont need to maintain complex routing in my WebAPI

I tried to do the following:

```
public class VoiceController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/IncomingTwilioVoice")]
        public IHttpActionResult IncomingTwilioVoice(Twilio.AspNet.Common.VoiceRequest request)
        {
            var response = new MessagingResponse();
            response.Message("Hello World");
            return Ok(response.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and got this in response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Message>Hello World</Message>
</Response>
```

but when i call twilio number and it goes to this endpoint i only hear "we are sorry, application error has occurred"

Update: I made some progress, when i changed 'content-type' header in response to 'text/xml' now it just hangs up without telling me about the error...

Update:
this is what i tried next:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("api/IncomingTwilioVoice")]
        public TwiMLResult IncomingTwilioVoice(Twilio.AspNet.Common.VoiceRequest request) //TwiMLResult, IHttpActionResult, HttpResponseMessage
        {
            var response = new VoiceResponse();
            response.Say("hello world!", voice: "alice");
            return new TwiMLResult(response);
        }
```

and my result is:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "?xml": {
      "@version": "1.0",
      "@encoding": "utf-8"
    },
    "#text": "\n",
    "Response": {
      "#text": [
        "\n  ",
        "\n"
      ],
      "Say": {
        "@voice": "alice",
        "#text": "hello world!"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but still "sorry, an application error has occured"

Comment: It appears that your result is a JSON representation of the XML that Twilio wants. Is there something you are doing to the TwiML response that is doing this?

Comment: @philnash, I ended up using 2nd way (changing content-type to "text/xml") because all of a sudden it started to work(kinda). My goal was to connect to a video room with a voice call but every time i try to initiate such a connection twillio end just hangs up without a reason. I already opened a ticket regarding this, but support is unable to reproduce an issue... stumped

Comment: Ok, glad this part is working now. I see you have some other questions on SO that you've asked, I'll see if I can answer those too and maybe we can get you progressing on this.